# Share API data with other components by using React Hook, NO REDUX

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm experimenting with Hooks without any state management tool (such as Redux), to get the same kind of behavior/structure I could have by using a traditional structure of classes + redux.

Usually, with a class base code I would:

- ComponentDidMount dispatch to Call the API
- Use actions and reducers to store the data in Redux
- Share the data to any component I want by using mapStateToProps

And here where the problem is by using Hooks without Redux: 'Share the DATA with any component'.

The following example is the way I have found to share states between components by Hooks:

//app.js

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import Routes from '../../routes'
import Header from '../Shared/Header'
import Footer from '../Shared/Footer'

export const AppContext = React.createContext();

// Set up Initial State
const initialState = {
  userType: '',
};

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'USER_PROFILE_TYPE':
      return {
        userType: action.data === 'Student' ? true : false
      };
    default:
      return initialState;
  }
}

const App = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AppContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
        <Header userType={state.userType} />
        <Routes />
        <Footer />
      </AppContext.Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default App
```

// profile.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext} from 'react'
import { URLS } from '../../../constants'
import ProfileDeleteButton from './ProfileDeleteButton'
import DialogDelete from './DialogDelete'
import api from '../../../helpers/API';

// Import Context
import { AppContext } from '../../Core'

const Profile = props => {

  // Share userType State
  const {state, dispatch} = useContext(AppContext);
  const userType = type => {
    dispatch({ type: 'USER_PROFILE_TYPE', data: type }); <--- Here the action to call the reducer in the App.js file
  };

  // Profile API call
  const [ profileData, setProfileData ] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUserProfile()
  }, [])

  const fetchUserProfile = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await api
        .get(URLS.PROFILE);
      const userAttributes = data.data.data.attributes;
      userType(userAttributes.type) <--- here I am passing the api response
    }
    catch ({ response }) {
      console.log('THIS IS THE RESPONSE ==> ', response.data.errors);
    }
  }
etc.... not important what's happening after this...
```

now, the only way for me to see the value of `userType` is to pass it as a prop to the `<Header />` component.

// app.js

```
  <BrowserRouter>
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      <Header userType={state.userType} /> <--passing here the userType as prop
      <Routes />
      <Footer />
    </AppContext.Provider>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Let's say that I want to pass that `userType` value to children of `<Routes />`.
Here an example:

```
<AppContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
   <Routes userType={state.userType} />
</AppContext.Provider>

and then, inside <Routes /> ...

const Routes = () => 
  <Switch>
     <PrivateRoute exact path="/courses" component={Courses} userType={state.userType} /> 
  </Switch>
```

I don't like it. It's not clean, sustainable or scalable.
Any suggestions on how to make the codebase better?

Many thanks
Joe

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the state as a prop to every component. Using context you can gain access to state properity in your reducer inside every child component of parent Provider. Like you have already done in the Profile.js

```
 const {state, dispatch} = useContext(AppContext);
```

State property here contains state property in the reducer. So you can gain access to it by **state.userType**

Comment: thanks for your reply. So, when you say "gain access to state property in your reducer inside every child component" what does it mean exactly? Because at the moment, the data passed from the Profile to the <AppContext.Provider> is NOT visible in any children. Without using props, what should I use in the Header component to access the Context state? useReducer OR Context Consumer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is within your context.

The only changes I would make is spread the data instead of trying to access it one at a time something like this

```
<AppContext.Provider value={{ ....state, dispatch }}>
```

then use `const context = useContext(AppContext)` within the component you need to access the data.

`context.userType`